# Quoted booleans with javax.json API

Tags: java, json, glassfish

How can I affect `javax.json.JsonReader` in order to treat quoted boolean literals as valid booleans. I.e `"foo": "true"` is the same as `"foo": true`, in Jackson it can be done with a custom serializer for boolean values (see: [How to serialize boolean to JSON as strings using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678340/how-to-serialize-boolean-to-json-as-strings-using-jackson))

I use glassflish as an implementation